# Peer vs Dependency for npm package

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am creating a react-native npm module.

The npm module uses React & React-Native Packages i.e say something like this

```
import React, { Component}  from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native' 

class something extends Component {

render () {
return (
<View> 
{/* Code */}
</View> 
)
```

Now, here adding should I add React and React-native as dependencies or peerDependencies and why?

Update: My current package.json for library (npm module)

```
"dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-native": "^0.60.5",
    "react-native-device-info": "^2.3.2"
  }
```

And For the app let it be something like

```
 "dependencies": {
      "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
      "react": "^16.9.0",
      "react-native": "^0.60.5"
    }
```

Does it look correct?

Comment: If based on my answer, `My current package.json for library` should do: 1. do not list `"react"` in `"dependencies"`, and 2. make `"devDependencies": { "react": "^16.9.0" }`, then 3. either `"peerDependencies": { "react": "^16.9.0" }` or `"peerDependencies": { "react": "^16.0.0" }` or `"peerDependencies": { "react": "*" }`, or any other reasonable version, depends on your implementation.

Comment: For the app, it could be correct, it still depends on your implementation; if the app needs `"react": "^16.9.0",` then you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

If your module is something like an ui library and to be installed into another react app, it should list react and react-native as **devDependencies and peerDependencies**. There should not be 2 versions of react (and react-native) in the host app, so in order to achieve that, use these 2 dependencies, they won't install anything in the host app.

**devDependencies**: describes the packages that you rely on when developing; you both need react and react-native so put them here; use any versions that you want.

**peerDependencies**: describes the packages that you require/suggest your host app to use, the versions should at least match your uses, so there could be a minimum version or not limited;

For example check this [package.json](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/package.json), when developing, this package uses "react": "^16.8.5" as "devDependencies"; and when being installed, it actually does not use any specific api belongs to certain version of react, so it uses "react": "*", as "peerDependencies".

---

References:

https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/

> What we need is a way of expressing these "dependencies" between
>   plugins and their host package. Some way of saying, "I only work when
>   plugged in to version 1.2.x of my host package, so if you install me,
>   be sure that it's alongside a compatible host." We call this
>   relationship a peer dependency.

https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file

> "devDependencies": Packages that are only needed for local development
>   and testing.

Comment: "There should not be 2 versions of react (and react-native) in the host app, so put inside these 2 dependencies and it won't install anything in the host app.". What do you mean?

Comment: @mAhMoUdDaFeR I edited my words, they were incorrect english, sorry.

Comment: @MarsonMao Updated my question, going through your answer